# custom discount applied twice in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have applied custom discount in magento 2.1 using [this](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-magento-2-custom-discount/). Everything is working on local system but when I deploy the changes on server, discount get subtracted twice from the total.
Can any one any idea about this?

Sales.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
<section name="quote">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="test_discount" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Model\Quote\Discount" sort_order="500"/>
    </group>
</section>
```

Answer (score 13):

To remove the custom discount applying twice in your summary .Just add below Lines

```
$items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
            if (!count($items)) {
                return $this;
            }
```

in the collect method. Once done, it will look like below.

```
public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
    parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be because of multishipping.
Magento collects totals per address. In the default scenario a quote has two addresses: A billing address and a shipping address.
I have not tried the example you linked, but afaiks the fee will be applied twice. For some reason this does not show up on the frontend, but I also had problems where a fee was applied twice, but somehow still showed up correctly on the frontend.

I assume when having a multiple shipping order, there is still only one billing address. Therefore the following snippet should fix the issue of having custom fees/discounts applied twice:

```
$address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
if($address->getAddressType() != 'billing'){
    return $this;
}
```

Or, if you only want to apply the fee/charge for shipments with items:

```
$allBaseTotals = $total->getAllBaseTotalAmounts();
if(!isset($allBaseTotals['subtotal']) || $allBaseTotals['subtotal'] <= 0){
    return $this;
}
```

This means the example file in the tutorial you linked would turn out like this:
`app/code/Magestore/Webpos/Model/Total/Quote/Custom.php`

```
   /**
    * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
    * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
    * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    * @return $this|bool
    */
   public function collect(
       \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
       \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
       \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
   )
   {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        if($address->getAddressType() != 'billing'){
            return $this;
        }

        $baseDiscount = 10;
        $discount =  $this->_priceCurrency->convert($baseDiscount);
        $total->addTotalAmount('customdiscount', -$discount);
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount('customdiscount', -$baseDiscount);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount);
        $quote->setCustomDiscount(-$discount);
        return $this;
    }
```

Edit: 
It seems `if($address->getAddressType() != 'billing'){` does not work as I thought it would.
I'm using `if($address->getAddressType() == 'billing'){` for now as I'm not using multishipping.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing same issue.. Have you got any solution of this issue?

Comment: Hey, I tried the fix but.... unfortunately... every time collect() gets called, the address_type is always "shipping", leading to 0 being added as a fee. I disabled multishipping in the backend. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Discount is calculated by address in quote, since there are two address `billing` and `shipping` that why is calculated twice.

you can set condition on either `billing` or `shipping` that only calculate for shipping address or billing address.

here just put this simple if statement (from nbjohan answer) at the start.

```
$address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
if($address->getAddressType() != 'billing'){
    return $this;
}
```

now it will calculate only for one time.